# Unable to create table: Unable to execute HTTP request

Tags: java, aws

Me está fallando al crear una tabla , el código es este:

```
public class MoviesCreateTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-east-2")).build();
        System.out.println("registra bien");
        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
        System.out.println("se conecta con la bdd");
        String tableName = "Movies";

        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to create table; please wait...");
            Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(tableName, 
                    //partition key
                    Arrays.asList(new KeySchemaElement("year", KeyType.HASH), new KeySchemaElement("title", KeyType.RANGE)), // Sort key
                    
                    Arrays.asList(new AttributeDefinition("year", ScalarAttributeType.N),new AttributeDefinition("title", ScalarAttributeType.S)),
                    new ProvisionedThroughput(10L, 10L));
            table.waitForActive();
            System.out.println("Success.  Table status: " + table.getDescription().getTableStatus());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to create table: ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Este es el log que me sale:

```
registra bien
se conecta con la bdd
Attempting to create table; please wait...
Unable to create table: 
Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:8000 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

***EDIT2 : HE ENCONTRADO LA SOLUCIÓN POR SI ALGUIEN LE SIRVE,***

simplemente he quitado la línea del client , porque ahí estaba probando en localhost y he sustituido por esto:

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
.withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
.build();
```

Comment: `Connection refused: connect` - Acá señala que la conexión ha fallado, tu conexion es estable ?

Comment: Sí , estoy por cable. Hice al aws configure , pero no sé si tengo que configurar el endpoint(de alguna manera a parte de hacer aws(?)

Comment: No no, me refiero a la conexón a la base de datos, estás bien las credenciales ? estás teniendo respuesta del servidor ?

Comment: He probado a meter datos en tablas desde la consola en formato .json , y no tengo problemas al enviarlos a aws . En eclipse en teoría también los he configurado bien

Comment: En teoría tengo que hacer un Run Application en Eclipse , y debería valer , pero suelta ese error. Porque run as AWS SAM Local no vale tasmpoco en Eclipse

Comment: La región tambiébn está bien puesta

Comment: La conexión es a localhost?

Comment: Sí en localhost, he seguido el tutorial de amazon tal cual

Comment: Por favor, pon la solución como respuesta y luego, un rato después, podrás aceptarla. Así otros sabrán que la pregunta fue resuelta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***HE ENCONTRADO LA SOLUCIÓN POR SI ALGUIEN LE SIRVE,***

simplemente he quitado la línea del client , porque ahí estaba probando en localhost y he sustituido por esto:

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
.withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
.build();
```